# Intersection Observer (React) is duplicating data in my array

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-hooks, intersection-observer, react-tsx

I created an intersection observer using the following guide:

https://medium.com/@ogbopinamoses/how-to-implement-infinite-scroll-in-a-react-app-using-the-intersection-observer-api-3d8b3d88629b

However, I'm having a few issues.
The first one is that when i expand, collapse and then re-expand the section (controlled by hideSection), the array is being repeated over and over which results in 100s of React duplicate key errors.
Secondly, occasionally when i'm scrolling down the "page" value is incorrect, it seems to be called more than once and increases by 2 rather than 1.
And thirdly, even without expanding/collpasing/re-expanding, i occasionally get duplicate key errors.

All these records are completely unique with their own id's.
The paginated data from the api is always correct. I've verified with breakpoints and console logs.
I've tried playing around with the useEffects and the useInfiniteScroll in various different ways, to no avail. Any advice or suggestions are appreciated!

My parent component is as below:

```
export function Section({ combine }: SectionProps) {
    const [hideSection, setHideSection] = useState(false);
    const { ref, position } = useInfiniteScroll();
    const { serverData, isLoading, totalCount } = useFetchData(position, hideSection);

    return (
        <main>
            {!combine &&
                <>
                    <Group
                        totalCount={totalCount}
                        key="completed"
                        title="Data"
                        data={serverData}
                        hidden={hideSection}
                        setHidden={setHideSection}
                        isLoading={isLoading} />
                    <div ref={ref}></div>
                </>}
        </main>
    )
}
```

Its data is coming from a hook, as below:

```
export function useFetchData(page: number, isHidden: boolean) {
    const [serverData, setServerData] = useState<any>([]);
    const [totalCount, setTotalCount] = useState<number>(0);
    const [position, setPosition] = useState<number>(page);
    const { data, isLoading } = useApiGetData().usePaging(
        {
            pageNumber: page,
            pageSize: 20,
        },
        !!page,
        { refetchOnWindowFocus: false }
    );
    useEffect(() => {
        setPosition(page);
        if (!isHidden && position === page) {
            setServerData((prev: any[]) => prev.concat(data?.data));
        }
        setTotalCount(data?.totalRecords || 0);
    }, [isHidden, data, position]);

    return { isLoading, serverData, totalCount };
}
```

And the interserction observer is handled here:

```
export function useInfiniteScroll() {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState(0);
    const ref = useRef(null);

    const handleObserver = useCallback((entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry: any) => {
            if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
              setPosition((prev) => prev + 1);
            }
          });
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const option = {
            root: null,
            rootMargin: '0px',
            threshold: 1
        };

        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleObserver, option);

        if (ref.current) observer.observe(ref.current);

    }, [handleObserver]);

    return { ref, position };
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `useFetchData` hook, the `useEffect` has `isHidden` and `position` as dependency. I'm not sure why you would want to fetch the data again on hidden toggle, but the first issue that you've mentioned -

> The first one is that when i expand, collapse and then re-expand the section (controlled by hideSection), the array is being repeated over and over which results in 100s of React duplicate key errors.

is because of `isHidden` dependency, whenever you toggle the visibility, you're `concat`ing the `serverData` with the already available data, resulting in duplicates.

As for the second and third part -

> Secondly, occasionally when i'm scrolling down the "page" value is incorrect, it seems to be called more than once and increases by 2 rather than 1. And thirdly, even without expanding/collpasing/re-expanding, i occasionally get duplicate key errors.

You should keep the pagination state in only one place, having two different states and adding it with a side effect (`useEffect`) is causing it to update erroneously. Sometimes, when the data from server is served before the handler for the intersection observer has run, due to the condition `position === page`, you're yet again, `concat`ing the data with the previous data, resulting in duplicates.

Here's what you should do instead -

- Keep a single state for pagination
- Be careful with how and when do you concat the data from server.
- Most importantly, remove useless dependencies.

Here's one way to approach this -

```js
export function useFetchData() {
    const [serverData, setServerData] = useState<any>([]);
    const [totalCount, setTotalCount] = useState<number>(0);
    const [position, setPosition] = useState<number>(0);
    const lastPageRef = useRef(-1);
    const { data, isLoading } = useApiGetData().usePaging(
        {
            pageNumber: position,
            pageSize: 20,
        },
        !!position,
        { refetchOnWindowFocus: false }
    );
    useEffect(() => {
        if(lastPageRef.current !== position){
        setServerData((prev: any[]) => prev.concat(data?.data));
        setTotalCount((prev: number) => prev + data?.totalRecords || 0);
        lastPageRef.current = position;
        }
    }, [position]);

    function incPage(){
      setPosition(prev => prev + 1);
    }

    return { isLoading, serverData, totalCount, incPage };
}
```

```js
export function useInfiniteScroll(callback /* callback to increment page */) {
    const option = {
            root: null,
            rootMargin: '0px',
            threshold: 1
        };
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const observerRef = useRef(new IntersectionObserver(callback,option))

    useEffect(() => {
        if(ref.current && observerRef.current){
           observerRef.current.observe(ref.current);
          }

    }, []);

    return { ref };
```

```js
export function Section({ combine }: SectionProps) {
    const [hideSection, setHideSection] = useState(false);
    const { serverData, isLoading, totalCount, incPage } = useFetchData();
    const { ref } = useInfiniteScroll(incPage);
   
    return (
        <main>
            {hiddenSection ? "Show the hidden state UI" : null}
            {!combine && !hiddenSection
                <>
                    <Group
                        totalCount={totalCount}
                        key="completed"
                        title="Data"
                        data={serverData}
                        hidden={hideSection}
                        setHidden={setHideSection}
                        isLoading={isLoading} />
                    <div ref={ref}></div>
                </>}
        </main>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi @Oxts, thanks for the suggestions, I've given them a go.  The code looks a lot tidier, the only changes I made was to add 'data' as a useEffect dep on the useFetchData and to move the setTotalCount to above the if as we need to retrieve a count of the data before actually showing it (the count is retrieved within the same api call). However the issue persists in terms of the array. If i can provide any more detail, please let me know.

Comment: Could you create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for me to take a look at?

Comment: No problem. I'll try and reproduce it on codepen this evening.